# AWS Amplify graphql Subscription Filter Returns All

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

When using AWS Amplify graphql API, does a subscription filter require any further config beyond adding the filter object to the subscription options?

The [documentation here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/q/platform/js/#using-amplify-graphql-client) suggests simply adding the filter to the subscription.

**Example of the subscription:**

```
const subscribeDeviceState = () => {
    const sub = API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(onUpdateDevice, {
            filter: {
                id: { eq: "abc-123" },
            },
        })
    ).subscribe({
        next: ({ provider, value }) => {
            console.log({ provider, value });
            processDeviceData(value.data.onUpdateDevice);
        },
        error: (error) => console.warn(error),
    });

    return sub;
};
```

I have tried multiple parameters in the filter object but each time, whenever any items is updated the subscription returns values for that item, even if the filter does not match.

I have only generated the schema manually and I'm using the Amplify options to generate the graphql code and operations on push.

**schema.graphql:**

```
type Device @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: userPools }]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    reported: AWSJSON
    features: AWSJSON
}
```

**Amplify generated subscription:**

```
export const onUpdateDevice = `
    subscription OnUpdateDevice {
        onUpdateDevice {
            id
            name
            reported
            features
            createdAt
            updatedAt
        }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, I have tried this and encounter the issue like you, my solution is we will create another subscription and this subscription will subscribe on mutation that we are want to working. ex.

```
onRatingFCAttribute(id: String): ApplicationFinalCheckAttribute
  @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateApplicationFinalCheckAttribute"])
```